# Google Maps - remove ski trails?

Tags: google-maps

Is it possible to remove the ski trails? I've used the wizard, but since the ski trails were added after the wizard was made, I don't think the wizard has been updated to show how to turn off ski trails?

I've read the documentation, perhaps this is an oversight?

Comment: Turns out that this is not an oversight, but the feature is not public. Certainly it's possible to turn off ski trails and the approach we've taken is to turn off the ski trails (all roads) on the Satellite view and then turn them on, on the Map view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE:  ski runs and lifts are now classified as POIs. 
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35823580

---

Here is my hack to hide the ski slopes:

```
   map.setOptions({styles: [
  {
     "featureType": "all", // non valid, hide all
     "stylers": [{ "visibility": "off" }]
  },
  {
      "featureType": "administrative",
      "elementType": "geometry",
      "stylers": [{ "visibility": "on" }]
    },{
      "featureType": "landscape",
      "stylers": [{ "visibility": "on" }]
    },{
      "featureType": "road",
      "stylers": [{ "visibility": "on" }]
    },{
      "featureType": "transit",
      "stylers": [{ "visibility": "on" }]
    },{
      "featureType": "water",
      "stylers": [{ "visibility": "on" }]
    }
]});
```

You can see the result here: http://jsfiddle.net/69yG3/2/embedded/result/

Comment: I'd previously looked at this approach, and unfortunately this hides too much data, like the green of the forest, and any local businesses. I like the idea though!

Comment: the more i look at it; the more I'm satisfied that this is the closest we'll likely get in V3 Maps. Fingers crossed gets picked up by Google, and included in V4

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible as yet, the issue has been raised here: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5877

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @AndyG The question is "is it possible", so "it's not possible" is a reasonable answer.

Comment: In my opinion it is the use of the term `it seems` that makes this a comment rather than an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ski runs and lifts are considered "sports_complex" POIs. They can be removed using the following JSON style:

```
[
    {
        "featureType": "poi.sports_complex",
        "elementType": "all",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "visibility": "off"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```