# Google Maps API v3 hide "ski runs"

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is there anyway to hide ski runs from the Google default and terrain maps?

We can hide roads using the "featureType" road and setting visibility off. But there doesn't seem to be an equivalent for ski runs or trails.

http://techcrunch.com/2013/03/25/google-adds-trail-maps-for-100-additional-ski-resorts-to-google-maps/

Comment: Feel free to raise a feature request at https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I did just that https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5877

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my hack to hide the ski slopes:

```
   map.setOptions({styles: [
  {
     "featureType": "all", // non valid, hide all
     "stylers": [{ "visibility": "off" }]
  },
  {
      "featureType": "administrative",
      "elementType": "geometry",
      "stylers": [{ "visibility": "on" }]
    },{
      "featureType": "landscape",
      "stylers": [{ "visibility": "on" }]
    },{
      "featureType": "road",
      "stylers": [{ "visibility": "on" }]
    },{
      "featureType": "transit",
      "stylers": [{ "visibility": "on" }]
    },{
      "featureType": "water",
      "stylers": [{ "visibility": "on" }]
    }
]});
```

You can see the result here: http://jsfiddle.net/69yG3/2/embedded/result/

Comment: nice! Although a seperate featureType for these ski runs from Google would be the ideal solution, this is a nice workaround!

Comment: Update for December 2021: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70515382/551729