# Not Able to Turn Off Hiking Trails Layer in Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to turn off Google Maps Hiking Trails is a Custom style map but it is still showing in the map.

As you can see I almost turned off all the layers but the hiking layer still there!

Can you please let me know how to remove it?

```
[
  {
    "featureType": "administrative",
    "stylers": [
      { "visibility": "off" }
    ]
  },{
    "featureType": "landscape",
    "stylers": [
      { "visibility": "off" }
    ]
  },{
    "featureType": "poi",
    "stylers": [
      { "visibility": "off" }
    ]
  },{
    "featureType": "road",
    "stylers": [
      { "visibility": "off" }
    ]
  },{
    "featureType": "transit",
    "stylers": [
      { "visibility": "off" }
    ]
  },{
    "featureType": "water",
    "stylers": [
      { "visibility": "off" }
    ]
  }
]
```

[image]

[demo (jsfiddle from comments)](http://jsfiddle.net/dxLt9qbj/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;
$(document).ready(function() {
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(49.395505, -123.203317);
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 14,
    center: latlng,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
  map.set('styles', [{
    "featureType": "administrative",
    "stylers": [{
      "visibility": "off"
    }]
  }, {
    "featureType": "landscape",
    "stylers": [{
      "visibility": "off"
    }]
  }, {
    "featureType": "poi",
    "stylers": [{
      "visibility": "off"
    }]
  }, {
    "featureType": "road",
    "stylers": [{
      "visibility": "off"
    }]
  }, {
    "featureType": "transit",
    "stylers": [{
      "visibility": "off"
    }]
  }, {
    "featureType": "water",
    "stylers": [{
      "visibility": "off"
    }]
  }]);

});
```

```css
@import url('http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css');
 body {
  padding-top: 25px;
}
#map_canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.0/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="well">
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue? (where do we find these hiking trails?)

Comment: Thanks for reply GeocodeZip here is a Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dxLt9qbj/) of what I am asking? :-)

Answer (score 0):

To remove them, use this suggested work around:

```
[
  {
    "stylers": [
      { "visibility": "off" }
    ]
  },{
    "featureType": "landscape",
    "stylers": [
      { "visibility": "on" }
    ]
  },{
    "featureType": "administrative",
    "stylers": [
      { "visibility": "on" }
    ]
  },{
    "featureType": "poi",
    "stylers": [
      { "visibility": "on" }
    ]
  },{
    "featureType": "road",
    "stylers": [
      { "visibility": "on" }
    ]
  },{
    "featureType": "transit",
    "stylers": [
      { "visibility": "on" }
    ]
  },{
    "featureType": "water",
    "stylers": [
      { "visibility": "on" }
    ]
  }
]
```

(from the related issue in the issue tracker:  [Feature request: Add Feature Type for Ski Runs](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5877))

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/dxLt9qbj/3/)

[image: ![image without ski runs]

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;
$(document).ready(function() {
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(49.395505, -123.203317);
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 14,
    center: latlng,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
  map.set('styles', [
  {
    "stylers": [
      { "visibility": "off" }
    ]
  },{
    "featureType": "landscape",
    "stylers": [
      { "visibility": "on" }
    ]
  },{
    "featureType": "administrative",
    "stylers": [
      { "visibility": "on" }
    ]
  },{
    "featureType": "poi",
    "stylers": [
      { "visibility": "on" }
    ]
  },{
    "featureType": "road",
    "stylers": [
      { "visibility": "on" }
    ]
  },{
    "featureType": "transit",
    "stylers": [
      { "visibility": "on" }
    ]
  },{
    "featureType": "water",
    "stylers": [
      { "visibility": "on" }
    ]
  }
]);

});
```

```css
@import url('http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css');
 body {
  padding-top: 25px;
}
html,
body,
.container,
.well,
#map_canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.0/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&dummy=.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="well">
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks again geocodezip but I do not want every thing off! I just want to get rid of the hiking layer

Comment: Those aren't hiking trails, they are ski trails.  You might need to turn off everything then turn back on what you want to get rid of them.  Related issue in the issue tracker: [Feature request: Add Feature Type for Ski Runs](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5877)

Comment: Update for December 2021: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70515382/551729